# Can't append file extension to string C# asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to concatenate a file extension to a string but it doesn't work.  I have a dictionary as such:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

The keys get populated from the results of a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "Execute getTitles @Title";
            comm.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;

            using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    myList.Add(reader["Title"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

This list gets loaded into the dictionary keys but I won't go into the values because it shouldn't be relevant and you probably don't want to read dozens of code lines.

Once I'm ready to use this data, I do:

```
string fileName = title + ".jpg";
```

But when I debug like:

```
Debug.WriteLine("fileName: " + fileName);
```

It only writes the title value (without the ".jpg").  What could this be?

Comment: The problem is not contained in your code example. You may need to isolate it a bit and post the relevant code. There is no way to answer this question as it is currently written.

Comment: Maybe title contains newline character?

Comment: Try boiling this down to a [mcve]. I suspect by doing so that you'll find it yourself; but if not, others will be able to help at that point. There certainly isn't enough to go on, in the question as it stands. The Sql you've provided is going to be irrelevant to the problem (but you should put your SqlCommand in a `using` block).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the results from the SQL table did contain whitespace so I was able to add a Trim() to the results to get what I was looking for.

Thanks Optional Option for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad you've solved it. As predicted, the SQL provided was irrelevant to solving the problem of "Can't append file extension to string".